# Position a tikz tree based on interior node

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees, trees

How can I position a tikz tree based on an interior node, i.e. instead of defining the position of the root, defining the position of an interior node?

For example, consider the following code.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,multi,tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node {a}
    child {node at (1,0) {b}
      child {node {c}}
  };

  \node {x}
    child {node at (3,0) {y}
      child {node {z}}
  };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This code does *not* produce the desired output, but it shows what I imagine.

Desired would be two trees where `b` and `y` are at `(1,0)` and `(3,0)`, respectively, and the rest of the trees is normal around them, e.g., `a` is above `b` and `c` is below `b` respecting the `level distance`, etc.

Especially if `a` and `c` become larger trees, aligning the two trees at the inner node becomes tedious shifting work.

Comment: Please make your code into a compilable example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to prevent the nodes being placed as they are defined, you can use Ti*k*Z's graph drawing facilities with the `trees` layout library.

For example,

```
\IfFileExists{luatex85.sty}{\RequirePackage{luatex85}}{}
\documentclass[border=10pt,multi,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs,graphdrawing}
\usegdlibrary{trees}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \graph [tree layout]
  {
    a -- { b[at={(1,0)}] , c }
  };
  \graph [tree layout]
  {
    x -- { y[at={(3,0)}] , z }
  };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Compiling with LuaTeX gives the following result.

[image: trees around nodes]

You can stick to the more verbose syntax if you prefer and still use the algorithmic graph-drawing facilities. This is just more concise.

Comment: Too sad that there seems to be no solution for plain pdflatex. However, this works nicely in lualatex, so thank you!

Comment: You could set the baseline to a particular node with Forest or, for a `tikzpicture` in the environment options. But that is for the whole picture. Probably Forest could do it with pdflatex. Well, definitely, but you need to fake a root in that case.